# single word request for a person who gets the job done

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a SOP for university entrance and I'm on the closing statement. 
I want to describe myself as someone who gets their job done properly with responsibility...help!

Written in a context as in:

> I now have a strong desire to become a person who is a challenger, inspirer, and a _____.

Actually I guess it doesn't exactly have to be a single word, just fit for that blank.

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where you specify the slot in the sentence where this word is supposed to go?

Comment: Urban slang is Hitta

Comment: He is a real go getter

Answer (score 5):

**"diligent"** and **"assiduous"** come to mind.

EDIT - As the question has been edited, I then suggest **"a diligent and assiduous professional"**, **"a model for my colleagues"**, **"a mirror"**.

> - [**diligent**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diligent) (adj) -  "careful and persevering in carrying out tasks or duties" (dilligent connotes steady, meticulous attention to an ongoing job or task. - **a diligent student**, **a diligent search,** etc.)

"They have won international renown for their **diligent efforts** to track down software bugs." (Hiawatha Bray) [TFL](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/_/search/Search.aspx?By=0&SearchBy=4&q=assiduous)

> - [**assiduous**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assiduous) (adj) - showing or characterized by persistent attention or untiring application: **an assiduous worker** who strove for perfection; did **assiduous research** before writing the book.

"And he was not going to have his vanities provoked by contact with the showy worldly successes of the capital, but to live among people who could hold no rivalry with that pursuit of a great idea which was to be a twin object with **the assiduous practice of his profession.**" (George Eliot) [TFL](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/_/search/Search.aspx?By=0&SearchBy=4&q=assiduous)

EDIT - The question has been edited so I

Answer (score 1):

You sound like a real ***[doer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doer)***:

> 1. a person or thing that does something, esp. a person who gets things done with vigor and efficiency.
> 2. a person characterized by action, as distinguished from one given to contemplation.

Answer (score 1):

***achiever***

***go-getter*** (this one's mentioned in a comment already)

***high-flier***

From macmillandictionary.com:

> [**achiever**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/achiever) *NOUN* someone who is successful because they are determined and work hard
>
> ***high/low* achiever** (=someone who is extremely
> successful/not very successful in life): Bob’s not what you would call
> one of life’s high achievers.
>
> [**go-getter**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-getter)
> *NOUN [COUNTABLE] INFORMAL*
>
> someone who is determined to succeed and who works hard to achieve
> this. You can describe someone like this as go-getting.
>
> She has a
> reputation as a real go-getter.; a go-getting young business executive.
>
> [**high-flier**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/high-flier)
> *NOUN [COUNTABLE]*
>
> someone who has achieved a lot and is determined to continue being
> successful

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a Yiddish/German expression which is frequently used in English, a *macher* (*ch* pronounced as in Scottish *loch*). But it may be a bit too strong for your needs.